# Is the sentence onomatopoeia or simile?

Tags: onomatopoeia, simile

“I’m letting the idea of hacking the robot go when we hear a buzz, like a delivery drone.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's both. Buzz is an onomatopoeia, in that the word uses english letter sounds to imitate a noise that exists outside of language. Next, "like a delivery drone" draws an association or similarity between the sound that the robot presumably makes upon starting up and the sound that a delivery drone makes. To annoyingly respond to way more than what was asked, I'd add that this is a relatively weak simile. Looking at oxford dictionary:

"A simile a figure of speech involving the comparison of one thing with another thing of *a different kind*, used to make a description more emphatic or vivid (e.g., as brave as a lion, crazy like a fox)."

Robots and delivery drones barely classify as being 'of different kinds", so it feels a little like saying "this lion is as brave as a lion", or "this fox is crazy like a fox". The robot and delivery drones don't feel like they're being distinguished by any specific feature here. The only thing that saves it in my eyes and makes it still a simile is that the sentence is not just saying robots in general buzz, but that this particular robot, which I assume isn't a delivery drone, makes the same buzz sound as do delivery drones.

Finally, the sentence feels a bit clunky, which might add to the confusion. The tenses feel off to me, the timeline of letting the idea go in relation to hearing a buzz is inference-able (lol) but not actually specified. The action of letting the idea go continues to happen at the same time as hearing the buzz, which makes the reader think that the robot buzzing has no effect on his process of letting go of the idea.

I'd say something like "I'm about ready to let the idea of hacking the robot go when suddenly we hear a buzz, like a delivery drone".

Comment: Weak simile or not, 'a buzz like that of a delivery drone' might be very helpful to someone in identifying a certain type of buzz. '**Buzz of drones is more annoying than [that of] any other kind of vehicle**
 Jul 2017  A NASA study has discovered that people find the noise of drones more annoying than that of ground vehicles, even when the sounds are the same volume' [[New Scientist; YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E400IFWcspg)].